# how to disconnect from WebRTC lobby in Godot 4?

Tags: networking, webrtc, godot, gdscript, godot4

Does anyone know how to disconnect from a RTC lobby after connection has been established so that the user can return back to like the main lobby (organized by main WebSocket server) and maybe join another RTC lobby?

so far I've tried functions like

```godot
#my rtc peer
var peer_rtc : WebRTCMultiplayerPeer = WebRTCMultiplayerPeer.new()
#Option A - works well but the once the host of previous lobby tries to connect a different lobby
#the 2nd user works fine and syncs everything, but the host can't see the other users
#close the multiplayer peer and re-create the mesh needed for RTC
peer_rtc.close()
peer_rtc.create_mesh(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution, that seems to be working so far...

```
var peers = peer_rtc.get_peers()
for peerID in peers:
    peer_rtc.remove_peer(peerID)
```